# MySQL query usage of Order by ASC and DESC

Tags: mysql

I have this query:

```
SELECT * FROM project as p inner join users as u on p.user_id = u.user_id
ORDER BY p.projectname, u.date_joined
```

Now what I want to `ORDER by projectname ASC` and `u.date_joined DESC`.

How could I make it this way? I tried this code here but doesn't work:

```
SELECT * FROM project as p inner join users as u on p.user_id = u.user_id
ORDER BY p.projectname ASC, u.date_joined DESC
```

Order the projectname ascending works but the descending won't work.

Comment: Please [edit] to add a specific problem statement — "it doesn't work" can be assumed, but *how* does it not work? What error message or incorrect behavior is characteristic?

Comment: please show us input, desired output and output you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

To order project name descending, do this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM project p 
INNER JOIN users u ON p.user_id = u.user_id
ORDER BY p.projectname DESC, u.date_joined DESC
```

This will order your result by projectname desc (Z to A) first. For identical projectname records, date_joined will be used for sorting further (latest date first).